# Create a gtest filter without wildcard

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

It's possible to create a GoogleTest filter without wildcard in it ?

I have a test suite TestSuiteA

```
TEST_P(TestSuiteA, Blabla) {
   // ...
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Apple, TestSuiteA, testing::Combine(...));

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Ananas, TestSuiteA, testing::Combine(...));
```

And a second test suite TestSuiteB

```
TEST_P(TestSuiteB, Kokoko) {
   // ...
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Apple, TestSuiteB, testing::Combine(...));

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Ananas, TestSuiteB, testing::Combine(...));
```

I know precisely which tests I want to launch, so I don't want use the wildcard.

My filter

```
Apple/TestSuiteA:Apple/TestSuiteB
```

But it doesn't work -> 0 tests to launch

But with this

```
Apple/TestSuiteA.*:Apple/TestSuiteB.*
```

It works

What does this .* mean and why it doesn't work without ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each tests needs to have a unique name, and you haven't provided the exact correct name. That's why no tests were run. Make sure you know how exactly the tests are named - you can use `--gtest_list_tests` to list all the test cases defined in a given test executable. Then use the exact names with `--gtest_filter` separated with `:`. To read more how to run multiple tests, see [gtest advanced documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#running-a-subset-of-the-tests).

Comment: In my example, the .* should be replaced by .Blabla/0 and .Kokoko/0
The solution should be : Apple/TestSuiteA.Blabla/0:Apple/TestSuiteB.Kokoko/0 (where 0 is the number of the parametrized test (depends on the combination defined in the Combine section)